# Define and draw a hyperplane for hierarchical clustering result

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I used `hclust` on my data and got a two-cluster solution. Then I used the `scatter3d()` to create a 3D scatterplot to visualize the two clusters by getting x, y,z coordinates multidemsional scaling (see below).
I am wondering how can I define and draw a linear discrminant hyperplane that separate these two clusters.

[image: 3d scatterplot of two clusters in x, y, z space]

Comment: Whip up a small reproducible example and code where you get stuck.

Comment: basically, I just don't know what is a good command for finding a discriminant hyperplane. surface3d seems to be the one for plotting it, but I don't see how can I define the x, y, z for three points to draw the hyperplane.

Comment: As the question stands it's risking of being closed as "looking for a tool". You could better your odds by providing some reproducible code people can copy/paste and start working where you left off.

Comment: You don't know how to define the hyperplane or how to code it ? (if it's the theoritical definition that causes you trouble then your question would be better suited for CrossValidated. If it's a coding problem then just follow Roman's advice so we can help you)

Comment: Just found this on twitter from @mdsumner: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/geometry/docs/convhulln

Answer (score 0):

The most useful and sensible answer to the first part of my question can be found here:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-May/239195.html

For the second part, I think surface3d() will do the trick.